# Update State in Flutter from widget in other file

Tags: flutter, widget, state, action

I am still pretty new to flutter and I am stuck on trying to update the state from a widget I have in another file. The main reason for the widget in another file is that I will have use for the widget in more than one screen. What I need to do is I click on a button in the widget, which presents a CuptertinoActionSheet. When I click on add I need to update the state of the cell (I want to change the backgroud color and some text, and add an object to a list. What would be the best way to handle this?

I am using a grouped list which is inside class _JobScheduleState extends State :

```
GroupedListView<dynamic, GroupObject>(
                        elements: _elements,
                        semanticChildCount: _elements.length,
                        groupBy: (element) => element['group'],
                        groupComparator: (value1, value2) => value2.date.compareTo(value1.date),
                        // itemComparator: (item1, item2) =>
                        //   item1['event'].compareTo(item2['event']),
                        order: GroupedListOrder.DESC,
                        useStickyGroupSeparators: true,
                        groupSeparatorBuilder: (GroupObject value) => Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                            child: Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Text(value.day),
                                Spacer(),
                                Text(value.date),
                              ],
                            )
                            // Text(
                            //   value, textAlign: TextAlign.center),
                          ),
                        itemBuilder: (c, element) {
                          return jobScheduleListItem(c, element);
                        },
                      ),
```

Here is the entire jobScheduleListItem file.

```
Widget jobScheduleListItem(BuildContext context, Map<String, dynamic> eventStr) {

  CalendarEvent event = CalendarEvent.fromJson(eventStr['event']);

  String status = 'Available';
  switch(event.eventStatus) {
    case EventStatus.OPEN:
      status = 'Available';
      break;
    case EventStatus.EXPIRED:
      status = 'Expired';
      break;
    case EventStatus.APPROVED:
      status = 'Confirmed';
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }

  Color backgroundColor = Colors.white;

  void _showActionSheet(BuildContext context) {
    showCupertinoModalPopup(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) => CupertinoActionSheet(
          actions: <CupertinoActionSheetAction>[
            CupertinoActionSheetAction(
              onPressed: () {
                backgroundColor = Colors.orange;
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
              child: Text('Add to Application'),
              isDefaultAction: false,
            ),
            CupertinoActionSheetAction(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
              child: Text('Cancel'),
              isDestructiveAction: true,
            ),
          ],
        ));
  }
  
  return GestureDetector(
    onTap: () {

    },
    child: Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(16, 16, 16, 8),
      child: Container(
        width: double.infinity,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: backgroundColor,
          boxShadow: const [
            BoxShadow(
              blurRadius: 3,
              color: Color(0x411D2429),
              offset: Offset(0, 1),
            )
          ],
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
        ),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(8, 8, 8, 8),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(8, 1, 1, 1),
                    child: Text('${event.startTime.get12HrTime()}-${event.endTime.get12HrTime()}'),
                  ),
                  Spacer(),
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(0, 1, 1, 1),
                    child: Text(status),
                  ),
                  Spacer(),
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(0, 1, 1, 1),
                    child: FlatButton(
                      onPressed: () => _showActionSheet(context),
                      child: Icon(MdiIcons.dotsHorizontal, color: Colors.black, size: 24),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: Does this solution work for you? https://stackoverflow.com/a/73333303/14028477

Comment: I had looked into something like this before. My question would be is the best solution for this to have my widget in a class with a stateful widget? As of right now the jobScheduleListItem is only a widget that is called from the GroupedListView in a state class.

Comment: You can use `StatefulWidget` and `setState`. It's a good solution for a normal app. Because you recently started learning flutter, I would not argue to learn any state management solutions instantly. First, rely on the framework itself, it provides you with every solution out of the box.